# Silverlight Dropdown-box alphabetically ordered

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-5.0

I've been busy with this for two days, and I can't get any further on it.

I have a Dropdown-box/Combobox (not sure what it's called) in Microsoft Silverlight, and my editor is Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. The Dropdown-box has to be alphabetically ordered, but I do not know where to find the source. This is what I do know:

1. If I select the Dropdown box in the Designer, I can see that the
   Data Binding is called "par_Customer(item)".
2. On the left side of the Designer is a list of tables, including the
   par_Customer table.
3. Almost all tables have the text "Edit Query" next to them, and by
   clicking on that the program opens a query editor with the right
   query in it.
4. The table I need, "par_Customer", does not have the text "Edit
   Query" on it.
5. When I right-click on the table, I get the options to Delete or Edit
   the table.
6. When I click Edit, I see a list of all the attributes (columns) of
   that table and its relationships, yet no query or anything
7. The Dropdown box is not filled by code.

What I would like to know: where do I find the source of this dropdown box? Where is it "filled"?

I would really appreciate any help or input on this problem, since I have no idea where to look any information will be of value.